# Hoffman and Kunze Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

From exercise 8 in sec 1.2 page 5.

Prove that

Each field of characteristic zero contains a copy of the rational number field.

I saw an answer that starts from definition. It goes:
since in a field of characteristic zero, 1 != 0, 1 != 1+1 != 1+1+1 ... Hence, the natural numbers are in this field. However, 1+1=2, 1+1+1=3 ... are not proved in this proof. The axioms of field does not say that 1+1=2, 1+1+1=3 etc.

So, is there a better proof?

Comment: By != do you mean $\neq$?.

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't know coding.

Answer (score 5):

To put this exercise in a more "formal" way, you should try to prove the following:

> If a field $F$ has characteristic zero, then there exists an injective ring homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow F$.

By a field homomorphism, I mean a function $\varphi$ which preserves addition and multiplications, obviously. The copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $F$ will be $\varphi(\mathbb{Q})$.

You can define $\varphi$ the following way: First define $\widetilde{\varphi}$ inductively by

- $\widetilde{\varphi}(0)=0$.
- $\widetilde{\varphi}(n+1)=\widetilde{\varphi}(n)+1$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$,

and for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^-\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ define $\widetilde{\varphi}(n)=-\widetilde{\varphi}(-n)$ (since $-n\in\mathbb{Z}^+)$.

You can show by induction that $\widetilde{\varphi}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow F$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

Now, if $q=\dfrac{n}{m}\in\mathbb{Q}$, with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus\left\{0\right\}$, then, since $\widetilde{\varphi}$ as above is injective, we have $\widetilde{\varphi}(m)\neq 0$ in $F$. Define
$$\varphi(q)=\dfrac{\widetilde{\varphi}(n)}{\widetilde{\varphi}(m)}.$$

You can show that $\varphi$ is well-defined, that is, $\varphi(q)$ does not depend of the choice of $n$ and $m$, and that it is a ring homomorphism. Then, $\varphi$ is the function you seek.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this proof seems to force fit a function $\varphi$ such that it is an injective ring homomorphism and that it maps the rational field to a certain field of character istic 0, F, since 1+1+...+1 will never equal 0. However, how does it answer the question of why 1+1=2 and so on? in the inductive step by setting n=0 we can find out that $\varphi(1)$ = 1. However, $\varphi(2)$ = $\varphi(1)$ +1 = 1+1=?

Comment: @user102484 You should not be confused about the meaning of $2$, $3$, and so on. In any ring, its just customary to *define* $2=1+1$. After all,  if you try to prove that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq F$, it would not be true in general (obviously). That is why in the exercise he asks for a *copy* of the rational number field. It's a ring that can't be distinguished from $\mathbb{Q}$ if you only analyse the operations.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that is where my confusion is. A copy means a one to one (injective) mapping between each element in Q and a certain element in F. So how is the fact that F is characteristic 0 made use of in the above proof? Simply because the φ function is injective and hence since φ˜(0)=0, no finite sum of 1 can equate to 0? But to do that we need to prove that no finite sum of 1 can equate to φ˜(0) right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\widetilde{\varphi}(n)=-\widetilde{\varphi}(-n)$?

Comment: @BijeshK.S Yes. Thanks